# Bitcoin transactions towards and from a Taproot

Tags: blockchain, lightning-network, testnet, taproot

I am trying to solve a problem that was given to me as study material for a coding test. The problem requests the following:

> Create two Bitcoin transactions in testnet, one spending towards a
> Taproot output and another spending from that same Taproot output.
> Each of the two transaction should also include an OP_RETURN output
> with the string "BFX" in it. Provide the txid of both transactions.

I am new to all this, so despite being a simple problem to lots of developers, I have been working on it for almost 4 hours, and I still have little clue about what I should do.
Any advice on how to perform what the problem requests will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be better if you asked specific questions on problem(s) you stumbled upon or thing(s) you didn't understand after 4 hours of work. There are already many StackExchange posts on Taproot transactions if you search for the label taproot or OP_RETURN if you search for the label op-return. If you are entirely new to this then there is quite a steep learning curve.

Comment: Happy to send you some testnet Bitcoin if you need it and you provide a testnet address